# jQuery Full Calendar Modal Not Displaying Month View By Default

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

So I'm using the fullcalendar plugin. It pops up via a Foundation modal. I set it up with the following javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 1000,
    defaultView: 'month',
    header: {
    left: 'prev, next, today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
    }
  });
});
```

The modal functionality works fine, and a calendar does indeed pop up. but instead of showing a default month view, it simply shows a compressed modal that has all of the header options I've specified but no month/day/week data. I can click on month and everything is fine, but I specified the defaultView so the user would immediately see the month view. I don't know what's up with this. . .

Comment: Can you present a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For anyone who encounters this oddity, it seems that adding the following CSS (provided you haven't overridden the default ids for the calendar) works:

```
#calendar {
  display: block;
}
```